# Specifying directory type when removing characters from directory name

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, rename

I'm using the following simple line of code successfully to remove a specified word from all file names in a directory:

```
for file in *.* ; do mv "${file}" "${file//UNWANTEDWORD}"; done
```

But what can I add to that code to specify only subdirectories in a directory and NOT files?

So to restate: I want to remove a specific word from every subdirectory name inside a directory which contains both directories and files, and have it not effect the files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Note: this assumes that your original glob expression `*.*` is correct, i.e. that you wish to loop over directories whose names contain a period character, like `foo.bar`**

You can make the shell glob `*.*` match only directories by suffixing it with `/`:

```
for file in *.*/ ; do mv "${file}" "${file//UNWANTEDWORD}"; done
```

Alternatively, add a simple directory test:

```
for file in *.* ; do [ -d "$file" ] && mv "${file}" "${file//UNWANTEDWORD}"; done
```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, your first answer was the simple answer I was hoping for, unfortunately when I tried it, I got error: "mv: cannot stat '*.*/': No such file or directory" :(

Comment: @ExisDeni do you **actually** have directories that have periods in their names?

Comment: The second option doesn't work either :( There is no error but none of the directory names change, just nothing happens.

Comment: steeldriver: uh...no i don't, oops. Thanks, I got it now: */

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find ./dir1 -depth -type d -name '*UNWANTEDWORD*' -exec bash -c 'mv "${1}" "${1//UNWANTEDWORD}"' mv {} \;
```

The above searches recursively through the directory structure.  If you want to operate only files in the current directory, `.`, then run:

```
find ./dir1 -maxdepth 1 -depth -type d -name '*UNWANTEDWORD*' -exec bash -c 'mv "${1}" "${1//UNWANTEDWORD}"' mv {} \;
```

#### How it works

- `find ./dir1`

  Start a `find` command and tell it which directory to look in.  If you want to start with the current directory, replace `./dir1` with `.`.
- `-depth`

  Search each directory's contents before the directory itself.
- `-type d`

  Search only for directories.
- `-name '*UNWANTEDWORD*'`

  Limit the search to directory names containing `UNWANTEDWORD`.  There is no point wasting time on directories that don't have this word.
- `-exec bash -c 'mv "${1}" "${1//UNWANTEDWORD}"' move {} \;`

  Run your shell command on each file found.

  (In the above, when the shell command is executed, the string `move` is assigned to `$0`.  This is unimportant unless the shell code generates and error in which case the error message use `$0` as the script name.)